# extend all ajax post with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to extend all my ajax posts with a csrf token from cookies. 
I've tried following:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if(options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST")
        options.data = options.data || {};
        $.extend(options.data, { csrf: $.cookie('cookiename') });
    });
```

But it doesn seem to get applied to any of my existing posts. My console returns:

Blocking Post Request: no csrf token parameter

If i console.log following:

```
console.log($.cookie('CSRF'), 'waah');
```

It logs fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the jquery version that you're using?

Comment: I use version 1.11.1 of jquery and jquery.cookie-1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `options.data` is not object, it's query string and that's why you can't merge two objects.

You should to append parameters to query string, something like this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if(options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST") {
        options.data += options.data ? '&' : '';
        options.data += 'csrf=' + $.cookie('CSRF');
    }
});
```

Comment: `options.data` return object.

Comment: In which version of jQuery? I tested it with 1.11.3 and `console.log(options.data);` returns string?

Comment: Sorry @vitozev, `originalOptions.data` that return object and not `options.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the following line :

```
$.extend(options.data, { csrf: $.cookie('cookiename') });
```

By this one :

```
options.data = $.param( $.extend(originalOptions.data, { csrf: $.cookie('cookiename') }) );
```

**Note :** By default `options.data` is a `String` and not an `Object` instead of `originalOptions.data`.

Hope this helps.